# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: but there is a main function

Tags: c++

The following code does not compile with clang++ unless I use a -c tag, which implies no executable is generated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Calculator
{
private:
    /* data */
public:
    Calculator(/* args */) {}
    ~Calculator() {}
    void PrimeGenerator(int, int);
};


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    cout << "Please enter two numbers: " << endl;
    int x, y;
    cin >> x >> y;
    Calculator c;
    c.PrimeGenerator(x,y);

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}

void Calculator::PrimeGenerator(int x, int y)
{
    for (int i = x; i < y; i++)
    {
        bool prime = true;
        for (int j = 2; j * j <= i; j++)
        {
            if (i % j != 0)
            {
                prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (prime==true) {
            cout << i << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
```

is typical for a missing main function, but there clearly is one. Any idea on what I might be missing?

Comment: Not sure if it causes the problem, but the second parameter of `main` must not be `const`.

Comment: Try dropping `const` from `argv`. `main` should have one of a few well-defined signatures; yours is not one of them.

Comment: Are you using `gcc` or `g++`? With `gcc` I'd expect `C` linkage (although your code is C++ code) and `main` must have C++ linkage in a C++ program. Edit: Just tried it myself - it wasn't that. I can't reproduce it with gcc or g++.

Comment: clang++ actually, could that be a problem?

Comment: dropping the const from argv makes it work, though it is somewhat undesirable in general

Comment: Well, your question says "_The following code does not compile with gcc_" - so, yes, it makes it really hard to reproduce.

Comment: Apologies. In my defense, I had also tried with gcc and it didn't work, though of course my problem is it doesn't work with clang++

Comment: It works fine in all `g++` versions I tried it with (5.1 up to 9.3). A minor detail: You are not using the arguments, so you should use the other valid signature: `int main()`.

Comment: Can you think of a reason why it would work as it is with g++ but not with clang++?

Comment: I guess clang++ only accepts the two `main` signatures mentioned in the standard. The standard also leaves room for more (implementation defined) parameters after `argv` (which is often used for `envp`). I'd expect `clang++` to accept that one too (even though I haven't tried it).

Comment: @Karl if the problem was fixed by removing "const" why did you accept an answer that says to change compiler?

Comment: Got baited by mijailciencias request for rep. Should have been more strict.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your code, as @Ted Lyngmo says, you need to compile with g++. Because is a c++ program. Your code runs smoothly in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019.

Comment: Using clang++ actually, is that not recommendable?

Comment: @Karl clang++ is perfectly fine. If it's stricter than g++, I'd actually see that as a bonus.